# I am facing issue with generating blank image with Highcharts Node.js Export Server

Tags: node.js, highcharts

I have setup the `Highcharts Node.js Export Server` in local with Visual Studio code.

Executed Below Commands.

`git clone https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server
 npm install
 npm link`

After this executing below commands

`highcharts-export-server --batch "infile1.json=outfile1.png;"`

Json File Data

```
{
    "options": {"xAxis":{"categories":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]},"series":[{"data":[1,3,2,4],"type":"line"},{"data":[5,3,4,2],"type":"line"}]}
}
```

[log file](https://filebin.net/b3t4do07twe514ke/vscode-node-debug2.txt?t=zy2bm5ph)

Comment: Could you provide the content of the infile1.json?

Comment: @pawel_d I have added the JSON file data.

Comment: A JSON file should only contain a chart's options (the options property in your JSON) if you want to use the batch method. The rest, such as a constructor can be set through an additional argument (--constr, see the full list of available arguments here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#command-line-arguments). If you want to use your JSON, you can run server with the highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1 and then you can send a POST request into it using CURL for example (more information can be found in the repo's readme).

Comment: @pawel_d It's working now. Previously was passing `Y` for CDN, After passing `code.highcharts.com` its working. But `Highcharts.com` watermark is there. How can I remove that?

Comment: You can disable credits by simply setting credits.enabled property to false. Take a look at the following API section: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits.enabled.

Comment: @pawel_d I have used `code.highcharts.com` As CDN so it will pass data to `highcharts.com` Or not?

Comment: No, it only means all required scripts were downloaded from the Highcharts CDN (they all are appended in the phantom/export.html file). That is also one of the reasons why you should set up the server on your side.

Comment: @pawel_d Same solution working fine in my one of the machine and after run on server its not working. I have checked `npm` and `node` version on both the side .Both are same but not working on server.

Comment: As for the required NodeJS version, it is >=6.4.0. Could you provide me with the effect from both servers? What do you mean on one it doesn't work? Do you receive any errors in console? What does the final exported image look like? Please provide me with logs and exported images. Also, be sure that you refer to an existing JSON file and that it contains only the chart's options (just as the --infile argument format).

Comment: As i am using node js 12 version on both of the server. Both of the machine doesn't so any errors on console but one can generate the image and second one generate blank 2KB image. I am passing json with only option data. For log how can i find that?

Comment: To enable logs use the --logLevel argument.

Comment: @pawel_d I have updated log file, please check.

Comment: It seems that the file isn't available anymore.

Comment: @pawel_d updated link. somehow its deleted.